# Magento1.9 - Getting error on save customer address

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, customer-address, checkout-page

I'm getting below error whenever updating customer address from backend and also on saveBilling on checkoput page.

```
Call to a member function setAttribute() on boolean in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data.php on line 80
```

Comment: There might be an observer which is being called on customer save address event and on save billing event, and this observer is trying to set an attribute which does not exist in your magento system. Try to find this code in your custom code and or in any third party module.

Comment: Please suggest for which event should I check?

Comment: alternatively, you can find that attributes which is causing problem by open file `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data.php` and in `factory` static function you can dump that attribute around line `$dataModel->setAttribute($attribute); `

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

There is a customer address attribute created by a custom plugin and `frontend_input` value was `NULL` for that in the table `eav_attribute`. I have updated `NULL` to `text`. Now it's working.

**Refer** :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27648176/4073217

Comment: Sounds good!! Happy Coding.